# Trying to find a student's grade by assignment number in Ruby

Tags: ruby

So I have a hash like the following:

```
data = {bill: [100, 95, 92], frank: [67, 73, 84]}
```

I'm trying to build it out so that it would do 95 if I put in :bill, 2.

I'm getting really caught up in the iteration.

I have, which hasn't worked:

```
 def scores (grade_hash, student, assign_number)
   grade_hash.map.with_index {|i, x|  puts x-i}
 end
```

Clearly I'm a novice at Ruby. Any suggestions?

Comment: `puts grade_hash[:bill][1]` prints `95`, because `arr = grade_hash[:bill] #=> [100, 95, 92]` and `arr[1] #=> 95` (assuming `assign_number` is zero-based).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def scores(grade_hash, student, assign_number)
  grade_hash[student][assign_number - 1]
end

puts scores(data, :bill, 2) #=> 95
```

Some explanation:

```
{bill: [100, 95, 92], frank: [67, 73, 84]}[:bill] #=> [100, 95, 92]
[100, 95, 92][1] #=> 95
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of ruby (2.3+), you can use the `dig` method of [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-dig) and [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) without needing a custom method for this, though the index you pass in still needs to be 0-based:

```
data.dig(:bill, 2) # => 92
data.dig(:bill, 1) # => 95
data.dig(:bill, 5) # => nil -- they haven't taken 6 tests, yet
data.dig(:john, 1) # => nil -- there is no student 'john'
```